# Failed install npm i -g meteor-em

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor

Failed install meteor-em. I have install fibers@1.0.1     node-gyp
    node -v 5.6.0. 
Version python installed 2.7.5.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

```
1518 verbose stack Error: fibers@1.0.1 install: `node ./build.js`
1518 verbose stack Exit status 1
1518 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
1518 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
1518 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
1518 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
1518 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
1518 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
1518 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
1518 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
1519 verbose pkgid fibers@1.0.1
1520 verbose cwd /home/h3dgeh0g/Projects/meteor_bastard/jira/node_modules
1521 error Linux 3.19.0-54-generic
1522 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "meteor-em"
1523 error node v5.6.0
1524 error npm  v3.6.0
1525 error code ELIFECYCLE
1526 error fibers@1.0.1 install: `node ./build.js`
1526 error Exit status 1
1527 error Failed at the fibers@1.0.1 install script 'node ./build.js'.
1527 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
1527 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
1527 error not with npm itself.
1527 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
1527 error     node ./build.js
1527 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
1527 error     npm bugs fibers
1527 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
1527 error     npm owner ls fibers
1527 error There is likely additional logging output above.
1528 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You should post the part of the log that comes *before* the error, as that is where you'll likely find the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `meteor-em` package had been deprecated in favor of `iron-meteor`.

Use `$ npm install -g iron-meteor` instead.